# log or Audit in spring and database for 2 purposes how much time a method, task and job took and also store caclulations for audit debug purpose

Tags: java, spring, logging, aop, auditing

Our application uses java / sql server. 
We have ETL jobs (around 35 for different upstreams) using sprint batch. Some of the code is in java and some in database. We want to track lifecycle of a job from database. E.g. when a job started, when a particular component got called, when a method / stored procedure got called and how much time that took. The purpose is to do health check which component is taking more time and in case some stored procedure takes lots of time in production we should be able to query database. Moreover, we also want to store intermediate calculations for audit and debug purpose.

This time tracking and intermediate calculations would be stored besides normal application logging.

Current solution we have implemented is normalized tables in database (e.g. Job, Task, status, etc) for which we have stored procedure wrapper and then have java classes as well to call those stored procedures.

We are not redesigning our application, so wanted to check what is the best approach to track such information. AOP? but I believe that usually gets called for before and after what about the intermediate calculations we want to store?

Our current approach is working, but it is cluttering code as method is doing logging & auditing, instead of just concentrating on the main logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A free and open-source tool you should consider is  [Jamon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/), it is a comprehensive monitoring framework that provides a lots of useful features:

> JAMon allows developers to track their applications performance and
>   behavior using predefined modules. There are modules that
>   automatically monitor : SQL, HTTP page requests, Spring beans, method
>   invocations, Log4j, and Exceptions. Other modules are often easy to
>   build. JAMon keeps track of the following metrics for any of the items
>   it tracks in the modules: hits, total, average, min, max and
>   concurrency (average, max, current/active) to name a few.

Now about storing calculation, I would suggest to break your methods in smaller sub-methods and then use AOP or any other tool to capture the returned value and perform whatever operation you want on these data.

In addition, if you need to have more details on the database layer I would recommend [log4jdbc](https://github.com/arthurblake/log4jdbc), which will give you nice audit and metrics around jdbc calls. For example you'll be able to get the execution time, the in and out parameters of called procedures, parameters provided to any statements.

You can even extends this tool to provide custom behavior (audit only some procedures, do something specific with collected data.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the options. JAMon and log4jdbc looks good, and also thanks for advice on the right way to use AOP if intermediate results need to be stored. Let me explore JAMon and log4jdbc, I might come back for queries. One quick questions though are both log4jdbc and JAMon, can be used in production or are they memory /cpu intensive?

Comment: Jamon is tailored for production, but not log4jdbc. However I've used a customised log4jdbc version on production to audit only a subpart of the system (stored procedures used to transfer data to external systems). The overhead is quite small compared to the procedure call itself.

Comment: I forgot to answer this earlier, have done now. Although i couldn't use your suggestion but right highlights the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Aspects are a very good way to isolate the timing code in one place.

Stored procedures seem unnecessary to me.  A simple SQL INSERT ought to do the trick.  It's fine if you're using the stored proc as an interface to hide the schema from users, but I doubt that this table will evolve much.

Logging, timing, and auditing are the "hello world" of aspect oriented programming.

Comment: Thanks duffymo, but would AOP allow me to track a job. i.e. which method started, which method finished and when? currently, i can query a bunch of tables with job name in the where clause, and it gives me row by row account of what happend during the job execution. Sorry I am new to AOP so please ignore if it looks quite basic.

Comment: Track a job?  Not if you don't tell it how.  A good way to manage that is to pass a GUID of some kind for a particular job and give it to the aspect to write it for each record.  Then when you query the database you can group entries by GUID and order them by timestamp to see what happened and when.

Comment: Cool, so may be i can use JobID which is unique. No one in my team has worked with AOP, infact team has just stared learning spring although everyone has around 5 to 8 years experience in java. roughly how much time you feel, it would take to learn AOP ? and roughly how much time to create an AOP framework for my requirement? As you said, it is hello world type program for AOP so i expect not much.

Comment: Moreover, is it possible to store intermediate calculations happening with method through AOP?

Comment: Create an AOP framework?  Why on earth would you do that?  Use Spring.  I don't know what "store intermediate calculations" means.  Those operations should be done by the methods you're timing.    Sounds like you're going to make a mess by asking AOP to do things it shouldn't.

Comment: Nobody's angry; it's good to be told when you're about to fall into a hole.